# How to find a imperfect substring?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list of substrings of equal length, for all of which I want to find a position in a big string. However tricky part is I should find also substrings which have limited number of mismatches (number of mismatches given, too). I thought I could do this with regular expressions, but I can't find how. UPD: I'm using Python 2.7.

Example:
Input string: `s = 'ATGTCGATCGATGCTAGCTATAGATAAAA'`, input substring is `s0 = 'ATG'`, number of mismatches allowed is n = 1. What I want is return an iterable, let's say a list, of positions: `[0,7,19,23,6]`, which correspond to position of 'ATG' (twice), 'ATA' (twice), 'ATC' correspondinly, as none of other 3-mers with mismatches don't occur in the string.

Comment: show some examples of expected output please

Comment: Normally, this is not possible with regular expression. The default implementation of regex in all the languages I have come across does not support this. The only library I know so far that does fuzzy matching is regex package.

Comment: Input string: `s = 'ATGTCGATCGATGCTAGCTATAGATAAAA'`, input substring is `s0 = 'ATG'`, number of mismatches allowed is `n = 1`. What I want is return an iterable, let's say a list, of positions: `[0,7,19,23,6]`, which correspond to position of `'ATG' (2), 'ATA' (2), 'ATC'` correspondinly, as none of other 3-mers with mismatches don't occur in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module supports fuzzy matching. For example

```
(?:foo){s<=2}
```

matches "foo", permitting 2 substitutions.

Take also note of this remark from the docs:

> By default, fuzzy matching searches for the first match that meets the
>   given constraints. The ENHANCEMATCH flag will cause it to attempt to
>   improve the fit (i.e. reduce the number of errors) of the match that
>   it has found.
>
> The BESTMATCH flag will make it search for the best match instead.

Example:

```
>>> regex.findall(r'(?:foo){s<=2}', 'xxfoo')
['xfo']
>>> regex.findall(r'(?:foo){s<=2}', 'xxfoo', regex.BESTMATCH)
['foo']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Levenshtein distance algorithm for help? It is used to determine how similar two strings are to each other.

Here is a naive implementation:

1. For i = 0 to len(haystack_str) - len(needle_str)
2. Let potential_match = haystack_str[i,i+len]
3. See what the Levenshtein distance is between potential_match and needle_str
4. If the distance is 0, you have a perfect match
5. If the distance is less than threshold, you have an imperfect but close enough match
6. Otherwise, continue to the next i

Answer (score 0):

Given what I have understood about your question:

Type 1

```
def diff_count(s1, s2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if s1[i] != s2[i]:
            count += 1
    return count

def diff_filter1(s1, s2, max_count):
    return diff_count(s1, s2) < max_count
```

Type 2 (more efficient)

```
def diff_filter2(s1, s2, max_count):
    count = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(s1) and count < max_count:
        if s1[i] != s2[i]:
            count += 1
        i += 1
    return count < max_count
```

And the Python code for [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance)

```
def LevenshteinDistance(s, t):
    len_s = len(s)- 1
    len_t = len(t)- 1
    if(len_s == 0): return len_t
    if(len_t == 0): return len_s
    if(s[len_s-1] == t[len_t-1]): cost = 0
    else:                         cost = 1
    return min(LevenshteinDistance(s[0:len_s-1], t) + 1,
               LevenshteinDistance(s, t[0:len_t-1]) + 1,
               LevenshteinDistance(s[0:len_s-1], t[0:len_t-1]) + cost)
```